# build vdproj from command line doesn't generate msi file, fine in IDE

Tags: vdproj

We have a vdproj build fine in VS2022IDE, however if we want to build from command line using devenv.com, it doesn't seem to generate the msi at all, although build doesn't show any error.

Also noted this is happened only recently, worked fine about 2 weeks ago

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" XXXClient\XXX_Client_Package\XXX_Client_Package.vdproj /Build "Release"

By looking at the log difference between IDE and cmdline, it seems pre-validation step never happens in cmdline, what could be the possible reason?

from IDE:

```
10:52:52:546    ------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'Amt_Client_Package' ------ 
...
10:52:52:923    ------ Pre-build validation for project 'Amt_Client_Package' completed ------
10:52:52:927    ------ Build started: Project: XXX_Client_Package, Configuration: Release ------
10:52:52:928    Building file 'D:\git\XXX\XXXClient\ZZ_Packages\XXX_Client_Package_#{Version}#.msi'...
10:52:52:937    Starting pre-build events...
10:52:53:205    Pre-build events finished
...
10:53:55:144    Starting post-build events...
10:53:55:484    Post-build events finished
10:53:55:491    ========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

from cmdline:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.7.4.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
Build started...
------ Build started: Project: XXX_Client_Package, Configuration: Release ------
...
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```